# "Error: A JNI error has occurred, please check your installation and try again" when run java program on eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

**Here is my code:**

```
package java;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        System.out.println("Hello, World.");    

    }

}
```

**Error I got in the console:**

```
Error: A JNI error has occurred, please check your installation and try again
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.SecurityException: Prohibited package name: java
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.preDefineClass(ClassLoader.java:895)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:1010)
    at java.base/java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:150)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.defineClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:862)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.findClassOnClassPathOrNull(BuiltinClassLoader.java:760)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClassOrNull(BuiltinClassLoader.java:681)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:639)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:188)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:520)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:467)
    at java.base/sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.loadMainClass(LauncherHelper.java:791)
    at java.base/sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(LauncherHelper.java:686)
```

Comment: FYI pure programming questions like these belong on Stack Overflow, not Ask Ubuntu.

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> java.lang.SecurityException: Prohibited package name: java
> ```

This error is telling you what the problem is: you can't use `java` as the package name (`Prohibited package name`).

This is because `java` is the package that built-in Java objects/etc are in, and it is a security risk to allow access to certain package-private classes/methods from your code (which would be allowed, if your code was in the same package). See [this stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3804442/why-java-lang-securityexception-prohibited-package-name-java-is-required) for more information.

The solution, assuming you aren't trying to mess with built-in Java classes, would be to use a different name for your package.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I understand it now.